# Tools to tell me why code is not compiling

Tags: compiler-errors

Are there any compilers/tools available for a new coder that can tell me why my code is not executing or at least explain the errors in more detail?

Comment: Most compilers explain their own syntax errors, and even till you which line the error occurs on.  Is there a specific syntax error you don't understand?

Comment: Would be helpful to know the language. Common ones can have more informative compilers available than obscure ones.

Comment: Can you tell us what language your using?

Comment: Thanks so much! Right now, Im learning Python and Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the language you are coding in there are several options.

I would look for an IDE(Integrated Development Environment) for the language you are coding in.

A couple that come to mind are: Eclipse(c/c++ and Java), Spyder(python)

These have a range of tools that can help you in your coding process, such as object/variable inspection and debugging tools.

Object/variable inspection is handy so that you can see what values your variables are holding. Typically you will only see the last value a variable was given due to the coding running faster than you can read.

Typical debugging tools allow you to step through your code line by line to see what is happening.

Combining the two tools above will really help you understand what is happening and where it is happening.

Also... google will really help you out when it comes to compiler errors. After a while of googling compilers errors you will start to gain an intuition for what your compiler is telling you.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey Scott, if you think that this answered your question... would you mind throwing the green check up on it? Have a good one!